# Regex to match middle string inside optional whitespace

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to create a regular expression that will match any given string (text or whitespace) inside of arbitrary, optional whitespace. The string itself could have whitespace in it;

I'm just trying to cut white space of the beginning and end, if it exists.

Example strings:

1. `one`
2. `t`
3. `three`
4. `four`
5. `five`

Expected output:

1. `one`
2. `t`
3. `three`
4. `four`
5. `five`

I've been testing on [regextester.com](http://www.regextester.com/) but have so far haven't been able to get it quite right.

`[^\s][\w\W]*[^\s]` will match cases 1, 3, 4, and 5, but it fails for single-character strings.

`[^\s]*[\w\W]*[^\s]` gets 1, 2, and 4, but it includes the leading whitespace from 3 and 5.

Is there a regular expression can handle this task? I'd also settle for using option 2 above and then trimming off the leading whitespace afterwards, but not sure how to do that.

Comment: What about `/^ +| +$/`?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need regex to strip whitespace. In python just use the `.strip` method of any text object. I am sure other languages have an equally convenient tool.

Comment: `.trim()` in javascript

Comment: I think trim is what I want. Thank you @MaartenvanTjonger. Don't know how I managed to miss that.

Answer (score 0):

In java you can use the .trim() method on any String. This will remove leading and trailing whitespace

" spaces at front and end.  ".trim() -> "spaces at front and end"